# generate context.Context from Done channel & GC of unclosed channels

Tags: go, garbage-collection, cancellation

**Background:**

I'm leveraging a custom LDAP-server [package](https://github.com/vjeantet/ldapserver). It uses a `Done` channel within requests to let the handler know if - say the client disconnects - and thus the handler should abort also. [For example](https://github.com/vjeantet/ldapserver/blob/master/examples/complex/main.go#L238).

Since a `Done` channel is the old way of handling cancelation - and my desire to support cancelation chaining - I created a `context.Context` from this channel like so:

```
func doneContext(p context.Context, done <-chan bool) (
    ctx context.Context, cancel context.CancelFunc,
) {
    ctx, cancel = context.WithCancel(p)
    go func() {
            <-done
            cancel() // done closed, so cancel our context
    }()
    return
}
```

This assumed that the `done` channel would be closed for both:

- client disconnects; **and**
- successful handlers (that run fully to completion)

The first proved true - the second did not. Successful handler calls would **not** trigger the `done` channel to be close - and thus I was leaking go-routines.

---

To solve this - and since I was canceling my own `context.Context` at the completion of the handler -  successful or not e.g.

```
// convert the client request's Done channel into a context.Context
ctx, cancel := doneContext(context.Background(), m.Done)
defer cancel() // clean-up context: rain or shine
```

I updated `doneContext`'s go routine like so:

```
go func() {
        select {
        case <-done:
            cancel() // done closed, so cancel our context (like before)

        case <-ctx.Done():
            // when our context is canceled, recover the go-routine (even if done never closes)
        }
}()
```

---

**Questions:**

- is this the correct way to upgrade an old-style `done` channel into a more modern `context.Context`
- should I be concerned that the external package I'm using is not closing the `done` channel?

  - i.e. will `GC` collect this channel, even if it is never closed?

Comment: Closing a channel is not a cleanup operation, and there is no requirement to close them. the [channel close spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Close) lists all the details about the operation.

Comment: Understood. The spec link however does not mention GC explicitly - so I guess by its omission its not a GC requirement.

Comment: Yes, the spec (and Go docs in general) can not list every possible thing you _don't_ have to do. The documentation is very good, so you can start with the assumption that the language is precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to close channels. If nothing is referencing the channel, it will be garbage collected.

Your channel logic appears correct.